# Modifying antdesign vertical timeline into horizontal timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I need to draw horizontal timeline in my React based app for which I am using [antdesign](https://ant.design/) as UI library. According to docs, [antdesign timeline component](https://ant.design/components/timeline/) is great resource in this regard but unfortunately it apparently supports vertical timeline only. Before moving on to looking for some other open source horizontal timelines or coding the timeline myself, I thought to ask here if there's any way to convert that vertical timeline into horizontal timeline. Here's the code snippet that I used to do some changes to get the desired results but didn't get any success:

```
import { Timeline } from 'antd';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Timeline>
    <Timeline.Item color="green">Create a services site 2015-09-01</Timeline.Item>
    <Timeline.Item color="green">Create a services site 2015-09-01</Timeline.Item>
    <Timeline.Item color="red">
      <p>Solve initial network problems 1</p>
      <p>Solve initial network problems 2</p>
      <p>Solve initial network problems 3 2015-09-01</p>
    </Timeline.Item>
    <Timeline.Item>
      <p>Technical testing 1</p>
      <p>Technical testing 2</p>
      <p>Technical testing 3 2015-09-01</p>
    </Timeline.Item>
  </Timeline>
, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use the `<Steps>` component instead, which looks similar but supports vertical/horizontal.

Comment: Though this doesn't seem the best suited solution but this is nearly the best solution for now because there's not focused support for horizontal timeline in antdesign and `<Steps>` component in this case solves the problem. It would probably not work in case of complex timelines but it work for basic purposes by writing some custom css as in my case.